# Refresh tooltip while still over the same control?

Tags: javascript, gwt

Is it possible to refresh a tooltip while it is moved over the same control?

I want to display a `tooltip` over a `canvas` (`canvas.setTitle("text")`). When the mouse stops, the tooltip is shown one single time. Then I have to leave the canvas and reenter to make the tooltip reappear.

But I want the tooltip to be redrawn when I move the mouse just within the canvas and stop again (goal is to provide a dynamic tooltip according to what is unter the mouse later on).

I can see that a `MouseOverEvent` is only triggered one time, and then as long as I move just within the canvas, the event does not occure again. Can this be accomplished?

Update:

I tried simulating a Hover event, but did nothing:

```
    NativeEvent event = Document.get().createMouseOverEvent(-1, 915,528,915,422,
          false, false, false, false, NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT, canvas.getElement());
    canvas.getElement().dispatch(event);
```

Comment: You'll have to use some emulation with JS and `onmousemove`.

Comment: I edited my answer. Just tried "faking" a hover event, but does not work either. I do never see a 2nd tooltip as long as I do not move me mouse out of the canvas and reenter.

Comment: how about fire your own event and let that change the dom?